# In Django-pagination Paginate does not working

Tags: django, pagination, django-pagination

- Python 2.6.2

  - [django-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/source/checkout) 1.0.5

**Question**: How to force pagination work correctly? The problem is that `{% paginate %}` does not work, but other `{% load pagination_tags %}` and `{% autopaginate object_list 10 %}` works!

Error message appeared, when I add `{% paginate %}` into html page:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /logging
Caught an exception while rendering: pagination/pagination.html
```

What I have done:

1. Install django-pagination without any problems. When I do in python `import pagination`, it's work well.
2. Added pagination to INSTALLED_APP in settings.py:

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       # ...,
       'pagination',
   )
3. Added in settings.py:

   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       "django.core.context_processors.auth",
       "django.core.context_processors.debug",
       "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
       "django.core.context_processors.media",
       "django.core.context_processors.request"
   )
4. Also add to settings.py middleware:

   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
              # ...
              'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
          )
5. Add to top in views.py:

   from django.template import RequestContext
6. And finally add to my HTML template page lines:

   {% load pagination_tags %}
   ...
   {% autopaginate item_list 50 %}
   {% for item in item_list %}
   ...
   {% endfor %}
   {% paginate %}

Thanks.

---

**ADDED**: Top of error report:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /logging
Caught an exception while rendering: pagination/pagination.htmlRequest Method:  GET
Request URL:    http://host:8123/logging?portfolio_id=1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Caught an exception while rendering: pagination/pagination.html
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node, line 81
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.2
Python Path:    ['/home/mosg/sources/django/apm', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_pagination-1.0.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.6', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 17 Jun 2010 06:29:45 -0500

Template error

In template /home/mosg/sources/django/apm/templates/accounting/logging.html, error at line 93
Caught an exception while rendering: pagination/pagination.html
83      <td>{{ item.transaction_datetime }}</td>
84      <td>{{ item.src_account }}</td>
85      <td>{{ item.dst_account }}</td>
86      <td>{{ item.body }}</td>
87      <td>{{ item.estimated }}</td>
88  <!--
89      <td><a href="./admin/accounting/transaction/{{item.id}}/">edit</a></td>
90  -->
91  </tr>
92  {% endfor %}
93  {% paginate %}
94  </table>
95  {% else %}
96      <p>No transaction logs are available.</p>
97  {% endif %}
98          </div>
99      
100 
101 </div>
102        
103         <br class="clear" />
```

---

**ADDED** for *stevejalim*:

```
@login_required
def logging(request):
    pid = request.GET.get('portfolio_id', 1)
    item_list = TransactionsLogging.objects.filter(Q(portfolio_id=pid)).order_by('-datetime')
    return render_to_response('accounting/logging.html', {'item_list': item_list, 'user': request.user,}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

PS: some edits required, because I can't django code style work well here :)

Comment: Are you definitely passing in a QuerySet and not a list or dictionary of the things you want to paginate?

Comment: @stevejalim I add logging function to the bottom of my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found earlier: [django-pagination](http://eflorenzano.com/blog/post/first-two-django-screencasts/) you need with of the latest version, which is fix the bug!

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details off TemplateSyntaxError?

All your configurations looks fine.
In `pagination/pagination.html` template there is `{% load i18n %}`. Do you have `USE_I18N = True` in your settings file?

Comment: Yes, `USE_I18N = True` presents in settings.py (it's default I think). Not working only `{% paginate %}`. If I delete it from the source html, it show only 10 items on the list, but no *previous*, *current* and *next* buttons presents. I can add error message, but it's too long...